# ReactJS get data from axios and pass to another compontent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called `Info` in this path:

```
compontent\Agent\Info
```

And get `data` from `axios` in `componentDidMount`:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        let data = await API.getData();

        this.setState({
            result: data.success
        });
    }
```

I add `data` to `state.result` and got `this.state.result.unread_message` here, now I want to pass `this.state.result.unread_message` to another compontent called `SideBar` , to avoid double request. Like this:

```
template\SideBar
```

**Code:**

```
<Label>{this.props.unread_message}</Label>
```

These are not child or parent, how can I pass `data` from axios in one component to another component?

I tried and followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428629) but it not worked as expected and also render whole sidebar in info!

Comment: Can you show case those two different modules i.e. how they are related.

Comment: @Tejas I think what he's saying is that they aren't directly related. They aren't coupled at all. They're in different parts of the app

Comment: @Tejas no relation, actually Info print user info like name and etc.., I passed unread message number to this component, I want to show this on sidebar (include, menu) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of answers to this question, some more complicated, some more standards-based, some which people would say 'never do this'.

One option: inside your Sidebar component, create a global function, `window.onDataUpdate = (result) => { this.setState({result}) }`, just as an example. And then, when you get the updated data anywhere else, you can call `window.onDataUpdate(result)`. A lot of people will think this answer is unacceptable because it uses a global function. Depending on the size and complexity of your project, perhaps that's true, this wouldn't be the right approach. If it's a real simple little project, I'd probably give it a pass though.

Another option is to have an object, stored in another file, that you can import into both files, that allows you to register listeners and trigger updates. So when your Info component gets the updated result, it can call the 'trigger' function on that other object, which in turn calls all registered callback listeners.

Or even use a normal default Javascript event that gets triggered with updated data. [following the guide here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

A common answer in React world for this type of scenario is to store the state with Redux as well. That may be over-complicated, especially if this is the only thing you'd be using redux for.

Comment: Absolutely right global thing is best approach vs redux which is pretty much complicated for only this thing. Other way is he can use localstorage of browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use react's `context API's` for that. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: I have never used context before, but I think it's time I finally tried

Comment: I using axios to get data from api, also use async await, what I see in context , don't think work in my case